# Python Flask on AWS beanstalk gives 502 gateway error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Pyhon Flask app is set to listen on port 5000 when deployed to AWS beanstalk. The app starts successfully. But when I try to access it. It gives 502 gateway error. Then I downloaded full log and check the nginx log, and found out it is actually forwarding request to port 8000. So I changed my app to listen on port 8000 and deployed again. Now the app failed to start, and in the log it has the error address already in use. Anybody having the same problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should kill your process running on port 8000 and then after that rerun the program the flask app at 8000 port. To kill process on port 8000 use this command if you are on Ubuntu ```kill$(lsof -t -i:8000)```

Comment: Or restart the EB instance.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally found out the problem. you will have to have *if **name** == "**main**":* wrap your *app.run()*

Not working:

```
app.run()
```

Fixed:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```